# Generic Type Repeated

Tags: java, generics

I have this class...

```
public abstract class LoadboardTable
{
    protected Map<String, HashMap<HasTableFields, String>>  table   = new TreeMap<String, HashMap<HasTableFields, String>>();

    public Set<Entry<String, HashMap<HasTableFields, String>>> getEntries()
    {
        return table.entrySet();
    }

    ...
}
```

In other classes, I am constantly repeating the generic type. For example...

```
for (Entry<String, HashMap<HasTableFields, String>> entry : myTable.getEntries()){}

Set<Entry<String, HashMap<HasTableFields, String>>> entries = otherTable.getEntries();

etc, etc...
```

This generic type is repeated and littered all over the application. Is there a better way? If I ever decide to change the generic type of the table Map object in the LoadboardTable class, I'll be changing it everywhere else too for days. Plus it's just a huge pain to keep typing it.

Comment: Consider encapsulating the lookup behavior in the `LoadboardTable` class, for example by adding a method `getTable(String)` that returns the `HashMap`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to avoid the repetition, except in the constructor, since Java 7:

```
protected Map<String, HashMap<HasTableFields, String>> table = new TreeMap<>();
```

You would have better code, and less to type, if you encapsulated the HashMap and entries in well-defined classes, though. It looks like you're using objects as open data structures, instead of using them as closed objects offering behaviour and keeping their state encapsulated.

Comment: Thanks. "There is no way to avoid the repetition" answers the question. On a side note, HasTableFields is an interface that Enums containing the field structure of the table implement (name, description, width). I have many different tables that are manipulated in vastly different ways. If I encapsulated all of the necessary functionality I would sacrifice cohesion for encapsulation. This is just a utility class that allows me to compare "tables" from different systems, with Set functions to get the complement between the tables, etc.

Answer (score 1):

3 Advises:

1. Instead of using so much generics, think about classes that you actually want to implement, instead of solving everything with generics.
2. Use the diamond operator with Java 7.
3. When using eclipse you can write just "getEntries" and then press CTRL+1 and click "assign to local variable" - this will automatically create a local variable with the right type. This does not solve the problem, but will make it a bit faster to write.

Comment: Thanks. #3 will help tremendously with the repetition. Would upvote if I could.

Answer (score 0):

```
public abstract class LoadboardTable<T,O>
{
    protected Map<T, HashMap<O, T>>  table   = new TreeMap<T, HashMap<O, T>>();

    public Set<Entry<T, HashMap<O, T>>> getEntries()
    {
        return table.entrySet();
    }
}
```